# How to get the selected value of Radio button into session variable in php

Tags: php, jquery

Please look at my code, here i just wanna get the selected radio button value into a session variable of PHP

```
<input id="r1" type="radio" name="<?php echo "s_option".$i;?>" value="<?php echo $ch_a;?>"><?php echo $ch_a;?>
<input id="r1" type="radio" name="<?php echo "s_option".$i;?>" value="<?php echo $ch_b;?>" ><?php echo $ch_b;?>
<input id="r1" type="radio" name="<?php echo "s_option".$i;?>" value="<?php echo $ch_c;?>" ><?php echo $ch_c;?>
<input id="r1" type="radio" name="<?php echo "s_option".$i;?>" value="<?php echo $ch_d;?>" ><?php echo $ch_d;?>
```

and script follows as...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{   
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() 
{
var radioVal = $(this).val();
<?php $_SESSION['val1'] = "document.write(radioVal)"?> //I am Not at all sure... Pls help how to do this
</script>
```

I know that PHP is a server side script and it doesnt know whats happening at client side. but i could not get any idea how to get it. pls help and thanks in advance.

Comment: @ravisoni how can i do this? pls help me yar

Comment: From the below accepted Answer the file at your-url.php is listening for ajax invoke and you will get the value like this $radioval = $_POST['rad ']; you can store this value in your session or in your DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is in your Javascript/jQuery section, make a call to your server and send it the radio button value. This can be done asynchronously (the call to server happens in the background i.e. no page refresh, for example, an ajax call).

For example (I may not be using the right syntax):

```
var radioVal = $(this).val();
// make call to server
$.ajax({ url: 'your-url.php',
         data: {rad : radioVal} ,
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert(output);
                  }
});
```

Then, you will have the value on your server (in your PHP script) using `$_POST['rad']`.

Comment: Is there any other way to store the radio button value in db using onclick event?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_SESSION['val1'] = "document.write(radioVal)"?>
```

Will not work as php sessions are stored at server so you need to send the data via ajax or otherwise you should store it in Javascript session.

Comment: if i store it in javascript session, can i get into php variable? pls suggest me how to do this

Comment: @Kalyan javascript session ?

Comment: @ ravisoni yes! Can i get it into php variable?